# JPA Ошиба при сохранение со связю ManyToOne

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

Здравствуйте, при сохранении entity `User` (`login != null`) получаю ошибку, подскажите что не правильно?

Есть таблица `users` и `login`, в таблице `users` есть колонка `login_id` (одно значение `login_id` может быть у многих `users`)

Ентити и связи

```
@Entity(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @MapsId("uuid")
    @JoinColumn(name = "login")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Login login;
}

@Entity(name = "login")
public class Login {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "uuid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
}
```

Сохраняю через `CrudRepository`, ошибка:

> org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to
>   persist: com.entity.Login

Comment: Что такое `CrudRepository`? Что-то не припомню в JPA такого понятия. Как создаются Ваши user и login, как они сохраняются средствами именно JPA. Можете привести кусок `CrudRepository`, который сохраняет? А вообще Ваш login = new Login()? Тогда наверное надо сделать Cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST} А ещё лучше делать всё вручную, не полагаясь на магию JPA, в порядке принятом в RDBMS. Магия не всегда работает как надо, большей частью это шарлатанство. Создали, сохранили login, Создали user, назначили ему уже сохранённый login, сохранили.

Comment: @Sergey [CrudRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html)

Comment: @Sergey сейчас проблема в том, если `CascadeType.MERGE` тогда новый `User` можна сохранить если `Login` с указаной `id` есть в базе, но если нет - ошибка, такое же поведение и для `CascadeType.DETACH & CascadeType.REFRESH`
Если сохранять новый `User` и новый `Login` _(не указывать `id`)_ все сохранится в базу (только с `CascadeType.ALL` или `CascadeType.PERSIST`), но не будет работать если указать `id` для `Login`

Comment: CrudRepository - это же интерфейс! Сам по себе он ничего делать не умеет! У Вас должен быть класс с методом save, содержащий конкретный код сохранить ентити.

Comment: Всё работает приметно так как и должно работать. Можете взять и почитать спецификацию JPA. Можете поспорить с разработчиками hibernate, если появятся разночтения. Даже среди разработчиков реализаций JPA нет согласия по некоторым моментам. Например поведение eclipselink в Вашем вопросе может сильно отличаться от hibernate. Поэтому не следует шибко доверяться никому. Почему у Вас login с id не работает, зависит от контекста в котором этот login назначается user-у. Но раз исходный код создания объектов и их сохранения - тайна, то и разбирайтесь сами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `Login` надо добавить связь з `User`

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "loginType")
private Set<User> user;
```

Comment: Не надо 1234567

Comment: @Sergey Вы о чем?